# ctexbook: fontset could not be found

Tags: windows, texlive-2023

```
Class ctexbook: CTeX fontset `' could not be found.
(ctexbook)  Fontset `windows' will be used instead.
```

[image]

Comment: Give minimal working example and your compilation command.

Answer (score 1):

You gave no example but the error means you have code equivalent to

```
\documentclass[fontset=\empty]{ctexbook}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Which produces

```
! Class ctexbook Error: CTeX fontset `' could not be found.
(ctexbook)              Fontset `fandol' will be used instead.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1678   { \ctex_load_fontset: }
                                
?
```

(and would probably produce a default of `windows`  in your machine)

Changing that to whatever it says it used as default should fix the error so

```
 \documentclass[fontset=windows]{ctexbook}
```

or in my case

```
\documentclass[fontset=fandol]{ctexbook}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works!